# I can't access the message variable of vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Message is not displaying in my blade @{{message}}

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

<section id="form">
<div class="container" id="app"> @{{message}} </div>
</section><!--/form-->

@endsection

@mainScript('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app1 = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
         data: function () {
            return {
              message: 'Welcome to vue'
            }
          }
    })
</script>
@mainScript
```

Why and how can we solve this ?

I'm using laravel blade does this not work with blade

Comment: `data(){return {message: 'Hello Vue'}}` data has to be function -> https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: message is not defined error showing

Comment: Can you post whole file?

Comment: Updated code please have a look

Comment: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Comment: this is not a component so the previous implementation was correct. but can you show the whole file with the part where you actually render this text?

Comment: As Vitaly said, you don't need data to be a function outside of a Vue Component. Are you sure you're outputting the `@{{message}}` inside `<div id="app"></div>`?

Comment: Updated the code that i have currently

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `<div id="app"></div>`. You have to place your vue code inside this div, as that's what you've set here `el: '#app'`.

Comment: can you look it again if i'm wrong share me code example ?

Comment: The Vue part is working fine. What is @mainScript - are you sure the `<script>` tags are rendering?

Comment: Yes when i do alert method it display correctly mainScript is fine

Comment: You're only loading Vue via the CDN correct? You're not loading it anywhere else and causing a conflict?

Comment: got it can't we create two instance in one file   var app1 = new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
         data: function () {
            return {
              message: 'Updated new instance'
            }
          }
    })

Comment: What is the process if i want to create two instance in one blade

Comment: Actually problem was in mainScript there someone already put new vue instance that was causing issue

Comment: So it's fixed now?

Comment: Yes but question is can we reate two instance in one file var app1 = new Vue({ el: '#app2', data: function () { return { message: 'Updated new instance' } } } inside same blade?

Comment: @suresh3 See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer to your comment.

You can have multiple Vue apps on a page like so:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

<section id="form">
    <div class="container" id="app1"> @{{message}} </div>
    <div class="container" id="app2"> @{{message}} </div>
</section><!--/form-->

@endsection

@mainScript('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app1 = new Vue({
        el: '#app1',
        data: {
          message: 'Welcome to vue app1'
        }
    })

    var app2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
        data: {
          message: 'Welcome to vue app2'
        }
    })
</script>
@mainScript
```

Comment: Awesome stew dellow, Actually i figured out and thank you so much for this

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it.